# shiny trigger refresh data - invalidate not working

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, invalidation

I have a shiny App that queries data from SQL. I'm running it on an internal server and want the data to refresh automatically every hour or so.

So far this only works whenever I put the shinApp files newly on the server and run it for the first time. Afterwards, whenever I reload the link, the data is not changing.

I tried using invalidate as below, but it does not refresh the data.

```
 shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  sourceData <- reactive({
  invalidateLater(3000000,session)
  return(sourceData())
})
.
.
.
})
```

where sourceData() is defined

```
 sourceData<-function(){
 data1 <<- get_data1( 'query here' )
 data2 <<- get_data2( 'query here' )
 }
```

Has anyone had this issue?

I saw reactivepoll() is another option. The valueFunc would be my sourceData,  but wasn't sure how to integrate the checkFunc in my context.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not looking to use sourceData() to return anything as this is the way it looks for me you can do one of the following:

## 1

```
 # sourceData() shouldn't return anything but it will still write into data1 and data2
    sourceData <- reactive({
      invalidateLater(3000000,session)
      data1 <<- get_data1( 'query here' )
      data2 <<- get_data2( 'query here' )
    })
```

## 2

```
# This is the preferred option as it seems to me you don't want to use sourceData() but rather the data1 and data2
sourceData <- observe({
  invalidateLater(3000000,session)
  data1 <<- get_data1( 'query here' )
  data2 <<- get_data2( 'query here' )
})
```

Also do look into [reactivePoll](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shiny/versions/1.0.0/topics/reactivePoll) and there are examples of how to structure it in the [reactivePoll and reactiveFileReader](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/reactive-poll-and-file-reader.html)

Comment: I edited the question. sourceData() does contain the query.  As for reactivePolling, how can I integrate the checkFunc in my context?

Comment: Thanks, as for 1)  this is what I had (after removing the return()). For 2) I tried the observe() option, but it does not stop refreshing the data in that case. Yes, I saw the reactivePoll examples, but how exactly would I integrate the checkFunc in my context?

Comment: look into example on the button here 

https://github.com/decastillo/forc/blob/3707586332af15b11a2eeec0c58687ffd1a978ff/aq/all_sessions.r